# OSB 11g installation failing at checking Operating system certification and checking service pack

Tags: oracle, service, bus

While installing Oracle Service Bus 11g, it is getting failed at the prerequisite check step.

It states:

```
Failed-Checking Operating System certification
Failed-Checking Service pack.
```

Comment: Which operating system is it, with which service pack installed?

Comment: Hi,
I am using Version windows 10.0.17763.437

Comment: Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/install.1111/e15017/before.htm#OSBIN249) says that Oracle Service Bus 11g works on MS Windows up to Vista; says nothing about Windows 10. Try to run installer in compatibility mode for one of versions mentioned in that document (for example, Vista or XP SP3).

Comment: What if i skip those errors and proceed.?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Try, and then you tell me.

Comment: The issue got resolved.                                                                                              Find your current OS version, eg : 10.0.02.0

Pick first 3 digits, i.e. 10.0, add line under <CERTIFIED_SYSTEMS> tag on refhost.xml file                                                                                                        <OPERATING_SYSTEM>
   <VERSION VALUE="10.0"/>
</OPERATING_SYSTEM>

Comment: Thank you for letting us know; I'm glad you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Find your current OS version, eg : 10.0.02.0

Pick first 3 digits, i.e. 10.0, add line under  tag on refhost.xml file

```
  `<OPERATING_SYSTEM>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on windows server 2016 with no service pack.
I added this code on this file `C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-XX-DD_HH-MM-12AM\prereq\win64\refhost.xml` in 'OPERATING_SYSTEM' tag for 'VERSION VALUE' value. And I think this is important to have all versions
`5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 6.0, 6.1, 6.3, 10.0, 10.1`